# How can I make my program simmply runnable on other machines by double click? Launch4j not working

Tags: java

I tried making it into .exe with launch4j but when i try to run it on other machine nothing happens, it works fine on my computer. I also cant run it when i leave it in runnable jar. How can i make it runnable on all machines by double click? Thank you

Comment: Do those machines have at least a JRE? If so not, did you embed one? Does your program use absolute paths on your machine?

Comment: i think it did, how can i make it work on every windows pc?

Comment: It should just work. Can you provide any more details? Are you collecting error logs from the program?

Comment: launch4j does work if configured correctly.  If you specify a JRE, you need to ensure the JRE is in the same "relative" directory on each PC.  Have you tried running from the command line to see if there's a specific error?

Comment: honestly i dont know, how can i make it work like launch4j does on every computer?

Comment: no error programs in launch4j :(

Comment: when i try to open it i get unable to access jar file :(